# DIsplaying and formatting multiple select fields values in a table in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have form comprising many  generated  multiple select drop from database only. Each select field has a different name. this means that each select field is an array with a different name. How do i loop through all of them at the same so that if any value(s) is/are  selected from it and  display it all at once?
Any assistance would appreciated

Comment: some code would be helpful, as well as what you've tried

Comment: @jmadsen Well thanks.  I tried to post the code with some html tags but it appeared distorted. anyways i have made some headway. The itch right now is looping different many multiple select dropdown with different names at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Just you foreach loop to set the values and name from database dynamically ...